# Bootstrap 4 Accordion Collapse / Expand All

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

I'd like to have a link (Collapse All) that will collapse all of the accordions and then change to "Open All" to open then all up again.

I haven't been able to find anything that works with BS4, only BS3.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a quick css class in BS4 that does that.
May be something like below could help !?

```css
#showall[data-toggle="collapse"]:after {
  content: "Hide All";
}

#showall[data-toggle="collapse"] .collapsed .show :after {
  content: "Show All";
}

#showall[data-toggle="collapse"].collapsed:after {
  content: "Show All";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<button type="button" class="m-2 btn btn-sm btn-success collapse show" id="showall" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#div1,#div2"> </button>
<div data-parent="#showall" id="div1" class="card collapse show p-3">
  Content 1
</div>
<div data-parent="#showall" id="div2" class="card collapse show p-3">
  Content 2
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/R1112/pen/YzKMGEp